# Where are the rich and poor living?

Tags: geospatial, population, gdp

Where to find a raster data set with population density and GDP per capita (global)? [Earlier examples](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/sdp-downscaled-gdp-grid-b2-1990-2025) use an even distribution of GDP per capita, which makes no sense if you want to compare other indicators in relation to income inequality. The resolution should be 1 degree or less. The goal is to see where rich people live and where poor people live. I am familiar with the GPWv3 dataset.

Comment: For the US, this is an interesting one: http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/income-segregation/philadelphia/

Comment: This dataset looks promising: http://gecon.yale.edu/data-and-documentation-g-econ-project

Comment: This data is not widely collected at high resolution on a global scale. It's hard to even guess who would be able to collect it. The US American Community Survey is one of the rare data sets that even approaches this sort of information at a granular level.